# Show the date on pictures

Tags: windows, date, properties, pictures

I have pictures, each with a date-taken tag.

How do I "stamp" that date onto the picture? (For example editing the picture, putting the date onto the actual picture, not just an overlay...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from the [Photography Stack Exchange Site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16953/how-to-overlay-date-and-time-onto-the-corner-of-photos).

This answer suggests using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)
I've never used this software, but it sounds like it would do the trick.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the command line?